# Computer crashing when I play games

Tags: power-supply, crash, power-management, gaming, overheating

Specs:

- Intel Core i7-3930k
- Corsair H70 CPU Water Cooler
- 16Gb DDR3 G.Skill 4x4Gb 1600Mh
- 120Gb Intel 520 Series SSD
- 2Tb WD Caviar Green WD20EARX SATA 6Gb/s 64mb Cache SATA3
- AMD Radeon R9 280x graphics card
- 750w CoolerMaster GX 80 Plus

Over the past two days, my computer has crashed whenever I play games. Two days ago, after a few hours of playing, **my monitors basically shut off, however I was still able to hear sound.** The next day, **my PC crashed again, this time with no sound playing after the crash**. The computer still makes sounds, so it is not fully off, as well as my keyboard is still lit up. The crash occurs after a few hours of playing, and once I restart and go into a game again, it happens almost instantly. This made me think it was a overheating issue, however my PC has been cleaned of dust, and various programs have shown no real heating issues.

Something to note is that in the BIOS, the cha_fan 1 / 2 / 3 were in red, going between 490 RPM to 580 RPM. We increased the upper temperature of these fans to 50c to have them running faster at lower temperatures, but after doing this and trying a game, it instantly crashed. I am not sure if this is linked in any way.

One other thing is that the Radeon R9 280x was installed about a month ago, due to the previous 7970 dying. It has worked perfectly fine, so I am not sure if that is a problem.

Things I have tried:

- Cleaning the PC
- Checking all plugs are in correctly
- Running a memtest (ran through 2 times)
- Increasing 6h4 fan speed

I was thinking that it may be due to the power supply, but I am not too sure how to check that.

Comment: I'm almost certain this is a problem with your graphics card... I'm sorry to be "that guy" but are your GPU drivers updated to the most recent versions? Also are you using an on-board sound device, or do you have a dedicated sound card? or, are you for some reason using the HDMI Output on your GPU and using the audio from there?

Comment: Haha that's okay. I have the latest GPU driver for sure. I don't have a dedicated sound card, and i'm 99% sure my headset is plugged into my motherboard at the back (although i'm unsure how to check.)

Comment: @BenFranchuk Okay so I used prime95 to stress test, and my computer didn't crash, but the moment I used FurMark to stress test my GPU my computer crashed. This definitely looks like a graphics card issue. Can you think of any other reason behind this? Just seems strange for the card to die out after only a month.

Comment: About all I can think of is that you don't have enough electricity to power the GPU under stress but this seems quite unlikely considering 750 Watts should be able to handle a lot more than you're throwing at it.